# UserForm is flickering and disappearing on Workbook_Open

Tags: excel, vba

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Sheets("01").Delete
Sheets("02").Copy before:=Sheets("02")
Sheets("02 (2)").Name = "01"
Form1.Show
End Sub
```

Form1 appears shortly (something like flickering) and then - disappears forever
If I run this code outside Workbook_Open event - it works well.
When I place it back into Workbook_Open - again flickering - and disappearing.
When I remove the first three lines (run only Form1.Show) - it works.
Please, help.

Comment: What code is in the `Activate` or `Initialize` methods? I'd assume something referencing one of those sheets is causing problems.

Comment: enderland, neither sheets nor form have any `Activate` or `Initialize` code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

--
sounds like it is just that you are seeing the code execute the requested processes.